# Adaptive font size based on font size in settings on Flutter

Tags: flutter, fonts

I am making an app on flutter.

So if my phone has normal font settings, it looks like this.
[image]

But if I have large font size, it looks like
[image]

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text 
The `AutoSizeText` starts with `TextStyle.fontSize`. It measures the resulting text and rescales it to fit within its bonds

code snippet

```
Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
              ),
              width: 100.0,
              height: 140.0,
              child: AutoSizeText(
                'Important',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
              ),
              width: 100.0,
              height: 140.0,
              child: Text(
                'Important',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
              ),
              width: 100.0,
              height: 140.0,
              child: AutoSizeText(
                'Important',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```